# How to open a new Konsole window from CLI

Tags: dbus, kde-plasma, konsole

Instead of running `konsole &`, which is slow, I'd like to open a new Konsole window using D-Bus, which is faster because it doesn't have to start a new Konsole process.

However, inspecting the interface with qdbusviewer, I can't find a method call that opens a new window.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out you have to use actions. You can list them with

```
qdbus org.kde.konsole-`pidof -s konsole` /konsole/MainWindow_1 org.kde.KMainWindow.actions
```

and you can call the action `new-window` with

```
qdbus org.kde.konsole-`pidof -s konsole` /konsole/MainWindow_1 org.kde.KMainWindow.activateAction new-window
```

From `qdbusviewer` I also found `org.freedesktop.Application.Activate` which also opens a new window but I didn't manage to call it using `qdbus`.